# Group and sum on multiple ids

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

My brain has locked up on the following problem.
This for an Bi Publisher report
Users can select one or several employee names from a multi select dropdown
e.g John, Peter, Ann ...
In table Emp we have:

```
emp_id | emp_name   
--- 
1     |  John  
2     |  Peter  
3     |  Ann
```

Table worklimit

```
emp_id |  limit |  from_date  |  to_date  
---
1    |     35  |    04-jul-2016 |  08-jul-2016  
1    |     15  |    11-jul-2016 |  15-jul-2016  
2    |     40  |    04-jul-2016 |  08-jul-2016  
2    |     20  |    01-aug-2016 |  05-aug-2016  
3    |     27  |    04-jul-2016 |  08-jul-2016
```

So the result I want is a total sum(limit) for the selected employee

e.g John + Ann 77
Or John + Ann + Peter = 137
This is just the first step. I need to sum up som values from a third table too, and I need to select a date range, and it must be grouped by week or month to make a barchart .

Can some of you clever brains out there point me in the right directions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(A.limit) FROM 
( 
    SELECT SUM(limit) limit,emp_name
    FROM worklimit
    JOIN Emp ON Emp.emp_id = worklimit.emp_id
    GROUP BY emp_name 
) A
WHERE emp_name IN ('John','Peter','Ann')
```

Comment: In this database users do not know anything about the emp_id. That's just an internal database id. So the where should be emp_name in(John, Peter, Ann)

Comment: Great. Thanks.
Now I have to put in my other selections and groupings and see how far I get before I'm stuck again.

Comment: @IdarKlubbenes What you said about user selecting names is entirely wrong. The user doesn't need to know about id, but the application where they may select one or multiple employees MUST know about id's. You can easily have two employees named Ann - and the user must have a way of choosing between them. (If it's not the id, then it must be another column or combination of columns that identifies an employee UNIQUELY - such as name, department and date of birth, or similar).

Comment: To clarify a bit.I used emp_name just as an example. They actually select from a list of unique resource ids but in the database the tables are joined by  "behind the scenes" objectids, these are never visible to the end user.

Comment: I'm just trying to get my head around joins and groups etc. Not easy to get the big picture in the start. Hopfully I see the light some day.

Comment: I don't see the light yet. How can I group the sums by month. I know I can use trunc(startdate ,'MM') but do I combine it with the rest?